# how can create django slackbot dynamically using python and django

Tags: python, django, slack-api

I am using aws for which i am creating dynamic server with a domain name of each server. Now my problem is that i need to created slack for each separate sub-domain but can't do it. All the domains are connected to the single slack app only. I need to this programmatically can anyone help me in this

Comment: You need to show your effort.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an backend app or a script file and import it on each server. This script would be able to create and config your app with slack using slack apis. Read more about slack apis for this.

I think that you should check:
https://api.slack.com/

Comment: can you please elaborate more